# How to load more items to a list when reach the bottom of results flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, grid

I have the code below which feed a list with 10 results from firebase. In this case it shows only the 10 items, now I wanna, when user gets the bottom of results, it loads more 10 items and add it to the list. I already have the scrollController and it works.. I receive the log "LOAD HERE" when I get the bottom of the results.

My doubt is how to add the new 10 items in the list?

```
scrollListener() async {
    if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == scrollController.offset) {
      print('LOAD HERE');
    
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.removeListener(scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  loadList(submenu ,callback, context, deviceSize){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: ctrlLab.loadList(submenu, 10),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          return Center(child: Text('ERROR!'));
        }else {
          return GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              Item item = snapshot.data[i];
              if (i < snapshot.data.length) {
                return Dismissible(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                  background: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    color: Colors.grey[800],
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.delete,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                    ctrl.onDismissed(callback, item);
                  },
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 5.0,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: GridTile(
                          child: Hero(
                            tag: "${item}",
                            child: item.imageUrl == null
                                ? setIconLab(item)
                                : CachedNetworkImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              imageUrl: setIconLab(item),
                              placeholder: (ctx, url) =>
                                  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                  Image.asset('assets/images/noPhoto.jpg',
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover),
                            ),
                          ),
                          footer: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  item.name
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );

              }
            },
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndLoading(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length + 1,
              crossAxisCount: deviceSize.width < 600 ? 2 : 3,
              childAspectRatio: 0.7,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Use Notification Listener widget it would be more efficient way and listen to scrollnotifications when it reaches max extent use a method to add more data in list used by future builder , here is [example](https://medium.com/@karthikponnam/flutter-loadmore-in-listview-23820612907d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another 10 data to the `crtLap.loadList(subMenu, 20)` and call setState inside the scrollListener to rebuild the widget about the changes.

```
var data = crtLap.loadList(subMenu, 10);

scrollListener() async {
  if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == scrollController.offset) {
    setState((){
       data = crtLap.loadList(subMenu, 20);
     });
  }
}
```

and use this data field to the FutureBuilder directly,

```
loadList(submenu ,callback, context, deviceSize){
 return FutureBuilder(
   future: data,
    builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
    .....
  ...
..
}
```

Comment: This reloads the list completely... I wanna add items to the bottom dynamically and with low computational cost

Comment: You can add items to the data collection when it has reached the bottom like `data.addAll([])`.  This time you just add the items to the collection instead of refreshing the whole list elements.

Comment: Yes, but with future builder it will rebuild all the items when i add

Answer (score 2):

**Infinite Scrolling in ListView**

I have achieved this case by using the local field instead of getting data from firebase. Hope it will give you some idea.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  ListViewDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListViewDemoState createState() => _ListViewDemoState();
}

class _ListViewDemoState extends State<ListViewDemo> {
  ScrollController controller;
  int count = 15;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(handleScrolling);
  }

  void handleScrolling() {
    if (controller.offset >= controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        count += 10;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List view'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('Item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(handleScrolling);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```